# Windows API to track if file was opened/modified

Tags: windows

I am using file auditing to track if a particular file was opened/modified (4663 Event).

I get more information, about which process was used to access the file eg: notepad.exe etc.

Is there any other Windows API/function I can use to do a similar thing?

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3517460/1748148) which has some options.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for would be a file system hook, and that unfortunately is not directly supported by Windows. This was discussed briefly about seven years ago in StackOverflow, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447856/hooking-into-windows-file-access but answers at that time were pretty unsatisfying, it seems.